# В чем преимущества ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, orm

Что дает мне использование Doctrine и Eloquent кроме скорости разработки(помойму спорный аргумент) и всеядности к субд(здесь конечно да). И как обстаят дела на практике, вы используете orm в своих проектах?

Comment: защита от внедрения sql-инъекций например =/

Answer (score 0):

Основная задача ORM - это обеспечить работу с СУБД в объектно-ориентированном стиле.
Если не использовать ORM, то придётся каждый раз, где это необходимо, вручную создавать инстансы объектов.

Если же программа разрабатывается не в ОО стиле, то в ORM нет необходимости.

Comment: С одной стороны вы правы (частично), с другой - я бы вас на клочки порвал (как Тузик грелку) за то, что вы приписывает ORM только одну задачу. Но это я с высоты могучего LINQ сужу (я заглянул к вам на огонек из стана дотнетчиков): с его помощью комбинировать сложные запросы по условию - просто сказка!

Comment: А вас похоже уже кто-то порвал нехило :)
Ваша проблема как-раз в том, что вы смотрите с высоты(что очень сомнительно) своего Линка, а не всемогущего Doctrine, о котором автор вопроса и спрашивал.